# Why is this iterator returning none with the expected output?

Tags: python

I am writing an iterator that should return all odd numbers from a giver iter. However, my code is printing none as well as the number I expect returned.

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    k = next(self.other_it)
    if (k % 2) != 0: return k
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in OddIterator([2, 7, 4, 6, 7, 5, 9, 8, 11]):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Because if you don't return anything, every function returns `None` implicitly so if `if (k % 2) != 0` is false, your function terminates and implicitly returns `None`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. How do I get my code to not print None?

Comment: You would need a loop to iterate `other_it` until you get an odd number.

Comment: @mammoth.co you also want to look at having `__next__` `yield` and not `return`...

Comment: @JonClements no, because then `__next__` would be a generator function and on each invocation it would return a generator object. You would have to implement `__iter__` to yield , but then it wouldn't be an iterator but only iterable.